# CursorLoader does not refresh when database changes

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-cursorloader, android-loader

I have a very plain `CursorLoader` that loads a `Cursor`. I store the cursor as a field in my activity. (So not in a `CursorAdapter`!)

```
    public static class BundlesLoader extends CursorLoader {
        public static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[]{
                BaseColumns._ID,
                TITLE,
                SUBTITLE,
                DESCRIPTION
        };

        public BundlesLoader(Context ctx) {
            super(
                    ctx,
                    URI_BUNDLES,
                    PROJECTION,
                    null,
                    null,
                    POSITION + " ASC"
            );
        }
    }
```

When I call `ContentResolver.notifyChange(URI_BUNDLES, null)`, I would expect the CursorLoader to reload, but it doesn't. (See `LoaderCallbacks` below; I log the callbacks.)

To debug this issue, I registered a little `ContentObserver`, which *does* work, oddly:

```
      getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(LegislationProvider.URI_BUNDLES,
            false, new ContentObserver(new Handler()) {
        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            Log.e("hello", "bundles changed!!!!!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
            onChange(selfChange);
        }
    });
```

So know I don't know how to debug from here. My `CursorLoader` initializes okay, my `ContentObserver` works, but for some reason the `CursorLoader` does not reload the Cursor when the underlying database changes. What can be wrong?

---

Here are my `LoaderCallbacks`:

```
    @Override
    public android.support.v4.content.Loader onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        switch (id) {
            case LoaderIds.LOADER_BUNDLES:
                d("Creating new bundles loader");
                return new Model.Bundle.Loader(getApplicationContext());
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Could not handle loader id " + id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(android.support.v4.content.Loader loader, Cursor cursor) {
        switch (loader.getId()) {
            case LoaderIds.LOADER_BUNDLES:
                d("onLoadFinished: Bundles loaded with "
                        + cursor.getCount() + " elements");
                mMasterFragment.setBundlesCursor(cursor);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Could not handle loader id " + loader.getId());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(android.support.v4.content.Loader loader) {
        switch (loader.getId()) {
            case LoaderIds.LOADER_BUNDLES:
                d("onLoaderReset: Clearing collection adapter");
                mMasterFragment.setBundlesCursor(null);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Could not handle loader id " + loader.getId());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do still need to call `setNotificationUri(getContentResolver(), URI_BUNDLES)` on the cursor even though you are using the `CursorLoader`. I don't know from your question if you are doing that or not.

Comment: That's weird, I can remember this was done automatically for `CursorLoaders`. Thanks!

Comment: I suppose I could call `Cursor.setNotificationUri(ContentResolver, URI_BUNDLES)` at the end of the query method in my `ContentProvider`?

Comment: Yes that's where it should go